# MembershipReboot with IdentityServer v3

Tags: identityserver3, membershipreboot

I am having trouble extracting UserAccount properties from MembershipReboot in conjunction with Thinktecture IdentityServer.  I have both up and running using the Sample repo here: https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot

When I request the "openid profile" scope in an Implicit Grant Flow, I am missing a lot of the user account fields such as "given_name, middle_name", etc from the id_token and response from the userinfo endpoint. I understand this is because they need to be assigned in the GetClaimsFromAccount function.

I can see the requestedClaims come into the GetProfileDataAsync() function in the MembershipRebootUserService class and if I hover over the instance of TAccount in GetClaimsFromAccount I can see the Firstname, Lastname, etc properties appearing in the CustomUser dynamic proxy but I can't for the life of me work out how to access them and copy them into the claims collection?

*More Info:*

I suspect the issue is with this line:

```
 claims.AddRange(userAccountService.MapClaims(account));
```

It looks like this should be converting the user account properties into claims but I dont get any back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it works is you add an option to your Scope object to return all of the claims for a user. **IncludeAllClaimsForUser** is the key property.

e.g.

```
new Scope
{
  Enabled = true,
  Name = "roles",
  Type = ScopeType.Identity,
  IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
  Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
  {
    new ScopeClaim("role")
  }
}
```

My request includes the `role` property as well. This pulled back all the claims for the user from MR for me. My example is with `Implicit` flow btw.

Comment: This does not appear to be working for me at all. I've tried adding this property to both the roles scope and the profile scope with no success. I am using a Hybrid flow... any ideas?